# Photos app - when I share a video to iCloud Photo Sharing - why does it get reduced from 1080 to 720?

Tags: icloud, photos

I have a video in the Photos library of the Photos app on my Mac.

If I right-click it and select "Get Info" - it shows that the video is **1920x1080**.

Next, I share it to iCloud Photo Sharing.

Then - if I right-click the resulting video in the Shared album - it shows that the video is now **1280x720**.

So - how can I share videos ***without reducing the quality?***

As a random aside... does anyone have any tips for how to search Google for help for an app as generically named as "Photos"?

Comment: Try "photos.app" and/or using Google's advanced search features, especially the negation and double-quotes: https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2466433?visit_id=1-636256620552919933-2842342595&p=adv_operators&hl=en&rd=1

Answer (score 1):

It's a limitation of iCloud Photo Sharing itself:

> iCloud Photo Sharing supports HEVC, MP4, and QuickTime video file types, and H.264 and MPEG-4 Video file formats. Videos can be up to five minutes in length and are delivered at up to 720p resolution.

Unfortunately, there really isn't any way around this right now.

source:  https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202786

Comment: Unless they want to export the photo to their PC directly from the phone.